# Call method twice in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I has this settings in startup file:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "register",
        template: "Register/",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "login",
        template: "Login/",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And this function in ClientsController:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(long? id)
{
    var model = _clientsService.GetClientViewModel(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

When i try to call `http://localhost:59824/Clients/Edit/25`
this query call `Edit` function twice. But in first call `id = 5` and in second call `id = null`.
Where is problem?

Comment: I created a new app locally with that routing and that controller and it got called once. Maybe you're getting a redirect from the view?

Comment: when i try to call http://localhost:59824/Clients/Edit?id=25 its call just once.

Comment: for some reason its try to call favicon.ico query 
http://imgur.com/a/8I2A5

Comment: Remove the nullable long from the route. Why would you ever want to put a null value in there? Chrome (and others) request the favicon automatically and you are specifying a default route which will assign, and match for, id=null superfluously.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it your `id` is favicon.ico, so it `null`. Find and remove favicon out of your project. I have met this problem and I fixed it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string instead of passing the id
in .net core:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
    {
        string id = HttpContext.Request.Query["id"].ToString();
        var model = await _service.FindAsync(int.Parse(id));
        return View(model);
    }
```

Also, using # in the src of a file in Razor file causes this problem.
remove it